# SUMIF only where value in column is a multiple of 100 in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, sumifs, sumproduct

I need to add values (expenses) from a column, only if the value in another column (accounts) is a multiple of 100.

We have a table where one column (A) has accounts and sub-accounts numbers (100,200,300, 303, 303.1,400, etc.) and another column (B) with expenses.

I'm looking for a formula in Google Sheets to sum all values in column B, only if the account number is a multiple of 100 (100,200,300...).

I'd appreciate any advice!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add input table and expected output table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=SUM(FILTER(B1:B, NOT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(".", (A1:A/100))))))
```

[image]

or just:

```
=SUM(FILTER(B:B; MOD(A:A; 100)=0))
```

[image]

or even:

```
=INDEX(SUMIF(MOD(A:A; 100); 0; B:B))
```

[image]

works too:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MOD(A:A; 100)=0)*B:B)
```

[image]